# When I run npm install angular cli with -g command in my computer in which place it will be installed by default

Tags: angular

npm install @angular/cli -g

When I run above command in my computer in which place angular cli  will be installed by default

Answer (score 1):

depends on the type of machine, you can find out by running `npm root -g`

Comment: when i run above commad I get path   C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Comment: yes, so that is the location where everything you install using npm with the global flag (-g) will be installed, each package in it's own folder (so for angular, probably @angular)